# Fetching content with JS from a redirected URL

Tags: javascript, json, redirect

Content is delivered via a JSON API to an app build on React Native (javascript). The domain of the API will soon change. To ensure the app has little to no downtime, the plan is to do a redirect:

```
old-domain.com/json-api?parameter=...
-> new-domain.com/json-api?parameter=...
```

When old-domain.com is nothing more than a redirect, will the javascript fetch() method still return the content as usual, but served from new-domain.com?

Comment: Did you contact the API team? Most probably they will do the redirect on their own behalf.

Comment: The API team is me. The question is not how to achieve a redirect, but if fetch() returns content the same way if requested from a redirected URL.

Comment: Given the url gets hit the same API endpoint eventually after the redirect, fetch should work the same. But what prevents you from changing the url in the react app?

Comment: If thats the case, then great! The app gets instantly updated, but updates roll out within 24 hours in the app stores. Some users might have deactivated auto-updates as well.